# Apiary multiple response

Tags: apiary.io

I'm documenting my api with Apiary and I'm using the old syntax of the blueprint.

I read somewhere about the separation of different responses with "+++++", but I do not know how to tell when apiary to use my first or second response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not possible, first response is always used.

Support for this will be landing soon, based on status code, content type and prefer header match. See http://support.apiary.io/forums/120125-general/suggestions/3264498-match-on-request-headers for more details.